# Amazon sign in/sign up suspicious problems

Tags: aws

I am trying to sign up for Amazon Web Services. I went through the whole procedure and there were no issues. It told me to wait 24 hours until my account was activated. I came back the next day, and it wouldn't accept my password. I tried many times but there was no luck. I tried making a new account the next day with a sharklasers.com email address, but it still wouldn't accept after waiting another 24 hours.

The next day, I had given up, but well browsing the web I found something very suspicious. I was typing an IP address into the Omnibox and this ip came up in the previously viewed sites: https://54.239.17.7/. What was even more suspicious was what it said next to it: Amazon.com - Online shopping etc. I clicked on the website, and chrome immediately blocked it because of 'phishing attempts' and 'connection intercepts'. It also said it can't verify the certificate is from amazon.com.

I have Bitdefender Network Security 2017 running on my computer and it is not reporting anything. How can I tell if my connection is being intercepted?

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with AWS

Comment: The IP is fine, it's Amazon. All that you have specified is that you can't log into AWS. Please contact AWS support.

Comment: Ok, but why is chrome telling me the ip is unsafe? Also, what site should've I put this question on?

Comment: Chrome is just saying the certificate is not correct, and that's because you are visiting the IP and no the URL. There is no site for this question because nothing is wrong.

Comment: This. The error is just because SSL needs a domain name to check the certificate against. You're not being intercepted. The Amazon issue is something we can't help with, the right site to ask this question would be their customer support.